# Searching element faster using document.querySelector in a large DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, css-selectors, casperjs, selectors-api

In a huge DOM with hundreds of elements, finding elements using `document.querySelector("input[name='foo'][value='bar']")` takes about 3-5 seconds for each element. Is there a way I can reduce this time? may be by giving full path of the element like say, `document.querySelector("parent child grandchild and so on` and then `input[name='foo'][value='Modem']")` or any other way?

I'm using CasperJS to test a large webpage and it takes really long to fetch each element and this is making my test run for an hour.. I've also tried `__utils__.findOne()` but the result is same 3-4 secs for each element. Since my test is focused on a very small part of the entire page, I wish if there's some way I could tell the `document.querySelector` to focus the element search on a particular portion of the page.

So could someone tell me whats the fastest way if any to fetch elements from a large DOM?

**Update**: This is how I measured the time

```
var init = (new Date()).getTime();
  var element=this.evaluate(function() {
        return document.querySelector('input[value='somethin'][name='somethin']');
    });
  this.echo('Time Taken :'+((new Date()).getTime() - init));
```

somehow the time is very high when I fetch radio buttons from the form, select elements and text boxes however returns within few milliseconds(I noticed this only today).

When I run the `document.querySelector('input[value='somethin'][name='somethin']')` in modern browser consoles like the chrome's , the time is less than a second.

I don't know if it has to do with the phantomjs's headless browser or something. Only for a particular page in that website, fetching elements is slowing down..

And yes, the page is very large with hundreds of thousands of elements. It's a legacy webapp thats a decade old. While on that page with IE 8 , pressing F12 to view source hangs IE for 5 minutes, but not chrome or firefox..maybe it's phantomjs's memory overload or something, rarely phantomjs crashes when I run the test on that particular page.  I don't know if this info helps , but I'm not sure whats relevant.

Comment: It would probably be faster if you could use IDs or classes. Browsers generally have optimizations for this because they're used so frequently in CSS.

Comment: The important thing is that the selector should start with something that can be found without searching the entire DOM.

Comment: These selectors are parsed right to left, so adding `parent child grandchild and so on` to the selector would probably slow it down, because it would have to make sure its ancestry is correct, instead of just the tagname and name and value

Comment: It is not believable that one call to `querySelector` takes 3-5 seconds. How did you measure that? I'd be surprised if it took more than a few dozen milliseconds even in a large document and complex query. In any case, you can call `element.querySelector` and it will limit the search to within that element.

Comment: Can you confirm that the DOM has "hundreds of elements", which doesn't seem that huge...

Comment: Did my answer really help or was the problem somewhere else? 3-5 seconds is a long time for a query. Is the problem that the page does not fit into memory?

Comment: @ArtjomB. your answer was helpful, I tried the document.children method but it didn't fix my problem much. I'm guessing my problem has to do with phantomjs memory issue or something, because for one it crashes rarely while trying to fetch elements and two I ran your code on that page in chrome's console, the time is only a few hundred millis.

Comment: @SheldonCooper I fleshed out my answer with regard to the memory issue a little bit. I still cannot reproduce such a significant slowdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### General considerations

The fastest selector would be the id selector, but even if you had ids higher up the tree, they would not get you much. As Ian pointed out in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919388/searching-element-faster-using-document-queryselector-in-a-large-dom#comment40573401_25919388), selector are parsed/evaluated right to left. It means that the engine would look up all inputs that have the matching attributes even if it is only one, and only then search up the tree to see if the previous elements match.

I found that if you can know in what enclosing element the inputs are, you can use JavaScript DOM properties to walk over the DOM and run `querySelector` over a smaller part of the tree. At least in my tests, this reduces the time by more than half.

### Memory problem

Judging by your updated question, it seems that it is really a memory problem. When you have *hundreds of thousands of elements* the relatively old PhantomJS WebKit engine will try to allocate enough memory. When it takes more memory than is free or even more than your machine has, the OS compensates by using swap memory on the hard disk.

When your script tries to query an element that is currently only in swap, this query takes very long, because it has to fetch the data from the high latency hard disk which is very slow compared to memory.

My tests run for 100k forms with one elements each in under 30 msec per query. When I increased the number of elements the execution time has grown linearly until at some point I got (by [registering to `onError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/phantom/handler/on-error.html))

```
runtime error R6016
- not enough space for thread data
```

So I cannot reproduce your problem of 3-5 seconds per query on windows.

### Possible solutions

#### 1. Better hardware:

Try to run it on a machine with more memory and see if it runs better.

#### 2. Reduce used memory by closing unnecessary applications

#### 3. Manipulate the page to reduce the memory footprint:

1. If there are parts of the page that you don't need to test, you can simply remove them from the DOM before running the tests. If you need to test all of it, you could run multiple tests on the same page, but every time remove everything that is currently not tested.
2. [Don't load images](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#pagesettings) if this is a image heavy site by setting `casper.options.pageSettings.loadImages = false;`.

### Test script

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var content = "",
    max = 100000,
    i;

for(i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    content += '<form id="f' + i + '"><input type="hidden" name="in' + i + '" valuate"iv' + i + '"></form>';
}

page.evaluate(function(content){
    document.body.innerHTML = content;
}, content);

console.log("FORMS ADDED");

setTimeout(function(){
    var times = page.evaluate(function(max){
        var obj = {
            cssplain: 0,
            cssbyForm: 0,
            cssbyFormChild: 0,
            cssbyFormJsDomChild: 0,
            cssbyFormChildHybridChild: 0,
            cssbyFormHybridChild: 0,
            xpathplain: 0,
            xpathbyForm: 0
        },
            idx, start, el, i,
            repeat = 100;

        function runTest(name, obj, test) {
            var idx = Math.floor(Math.random()*max);
            var start = (new Date()).getTime();
            var el = test(idx);
            obj[name] += (new Date()).getTime() - start;
            return el;
        }

        for(i = 0; i < repeat; i++){
            runTest('cssplain', obj, function(idx){
                return document.querySelector('input[name="in'+idx+'"][value="iv'+idx+'"]');
            });

            runTest('cssbyForm', obj, function(idx){
                return document.querySelector('#f'+idx+' input[name="in'+idx+'"][value="iv'+idx+'"]');
            });

            runTest('cssbyFormChild', obj, function(idx){
                return document.querySelector('form:nth-child('+(idx+1)+') input[name="in'+idx+'"][value="iv'+idx+'"]');
            });

            runTest('cssbyFormJsDomChild', obj, function(idx){
                return document.body.children[max-1].querySelector('input[name="in'+idx+'"][value="iv'+idx+'"]');
            });

            runTest('cssbyFormChildHybridChild', obj, function(idx){
                return document.querySelector('form:nth-child('+(idx+1)+')').querySelector('input[name="in'+idx+'"][value="iv'+idx+'"]');
            });

            runTest('cssbyFormHybridChild', obj, function(idx){
                return document.querySelector('#f'+idx).querySelector('input[name="in'+idx+'"][value="iv'+idx+'"]');
            });

            runTest('xpathplain', obj, function(idx){
                return document.evaluate('//input[@name="in'+idx+'" and @value="iv'+idx+'"]', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
            });

            runTest('xpathbyForm', obj, function(idx){
                return document.evaluate('//form[@id="f'+idx+'"]//input[@name="in'+idx+'" and @value="iv'+idx+'"]', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
            });
        }
        for(var type in obj) {
            obj[type] /= repeat;
        }
        return obj;
    }, max);
    console.log("TIMES");
    for(var type in times) {
        console.log(type+":\t"+times[type]);
    }
    phantom.exit();
}, 0); // just in case the content is not yet evaluated
```

Output on my machine (nicer):

```
cssbyForm:                  29.55
cssbyFormChild:             29.97
cssbyFormChildHybridChild:  11.51
cssbyFormHybridChild:       10.17
cssbyFormJsDomChild:        11.73
cssplain:                   29.39
xpathbyForm:                206.66
xpathplain:                 207.05
```

*Note:* I used PhantomJS directly. It should not have different results when the same technique is used in CasperJS.

Comment: This answer fails to explain what could possibly account for the ridiculous performance (3-5s per query) reported by the OP. Your experiment is interesting, but we are talking about milliseconds.

Comment: You're right, I should have inquired, how OP measured the 3-5 seconds. Initially I though this could happen, but after my own tests and 100k elements and still under 30 msec per query, I doubt this was a query problem, but rather some unnecessary `wait` or something like that.

Comment: The other possibility is that the DOM is so big, that it doesn't fit into memory and the OS is busy swapping. I ran into this problem when I tried 200k forms.

Comment: He said "hundreds of elements"; did he perhaps mean "hundreds of thousands"? Sure, in that case I can imagine things slowing down dramatically. And yes, your `wait` hypothesis sounds plausible. Or is he perhaps reloading the page on each test and the 3-5 seconds is page loading time?